# How to add socket support in ajax chat?

Tags: ajax, sockets, chat

Well,
i have a simple ajax chat application. It works in this way..
user sends a http ajax requests for new messages in 1 seconds interval.
server checks if there is any new message for that user, If there is any new message then server encodes in json format and sends to user.

now the question is how to combine ajax chat and also socket chat in same time? so a some user can chat using socket based device and some can use ajax..

Comment: all network communication is "socket based".  You'll need to be more specific.  Also, stack overflow is for helping with specific technical questions.  What have you tried/researched on this?

Comment: I know that all the communication is socket based.. For ajax we are using http port 80.  I am not a master in programming.
But as far as i know socket dost not store that message.
I just can not get it right, i would be nice if somebody guide or teach me that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I got a architecture that my solve this problem.
First,
When we use ajax based chat we all check for the new message and when we found a new message we show it to the chatters.
In socket programming, We throw the message when a new message comes based on target user.
So, Solution for that is,
We have to store all the data into database first and we have to check socket event in a interval like ajax chat.

It does not make scene because we are paying a heavy server load but, at the moment this is the solution.